# Do all my Moose classes have to contain 'namespace::autoclean' and 'make_immutable' or is there some way to get these by default?

Tags: perl, moose

According to the Moose best practices doc, my Moose classes should look like this:

```
package Person;

use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

# extends, roles, attributes, etc.

# methods

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

1;
```

See [Moose::Manual::BestPractices](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose::Manual::BestPractices#namespace::autoclean_and_immutabilize).

And 99% of the time this is what I want, so is there some way to have my namespace autocleaned and my classes made immutable by default so I don't have to have this code clutter?

Maybe there is a technical reason why it isn't possible or why it shouldn't be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

<strike>I think the only</strike> One way to avoid this is to use [`MooseX::Declare`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-Declare/).

[`MooseX::Declare`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-Declare/) is a `macro` which turns below into your example:

```
use MooseX::Declare;

class Person {

    # attributes

    # methods
}
```

It automatically inserts `namespace::autoclean` and makes the class immutable.

For extending classes you do:

```
class Person extends Human { ... }
```

And for adding roles you do:

```
class Person with BlueEyeRole { ... }
```

And you can easily combine these:

```
class Person extends Human with BlueEyeRole { ... }
```

You also get some other defined keywords, for eg. `method`:

```
class Person {
    has 'name' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str');

    method hello { "Hello " . $self->name }
}
```

If you did want to make your class mutable then its:

```
class Person is mutable { ... }
```

> Maybe there is a technical reason why it isn't possible or why it shouldn't be done?

Technically it would be difficult to pull this all together. [`MooseX::Declare`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-Declare/) makes use of [`Devel::Declare`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Declare/) to build the necessarily syntax for the Perl to interpret.

So if the boiler plate is an issue for you then consider using [`MooseX::Declare`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-Declare/).  I've used it on a lot of projects with no issues and find it ideal when quickly sketching together a class based app.  However most of the time I'm happy with the boilerplate and so stick with standard `Moose`.

Comment: Because it's wrong. MX::D is by no means the only way to achieve this.

Comment: @rafl: I said it was the only way I knew. So I don't think that deserves a down vote :(

Comment: Fixed preamble. What matters to the readers is if it really is the only way, not whether it's the only way that draegtun knows. :)

Comment: Thanks @Ether.  I was going to make similar change but got called away by my 4 year old :)

Comment: @rafl: Thats OK.  BTW, what are the other ways of reducing this boilerplate?

Comment: Thanks draegtun, MooseX::Declare looks nice, but I'm not sure I'm ready for another layer on top of moose just yet.

Answer (score 3):

I think [MooseX::MakeImmutable](http://search.cpan.org/~rkrimen/MooseX-MakeImmutable-0.02/lib/MooseX/MakeImmutable.pm) can do it for you.